# parse xml file from treasury.gov with pugixml

Tags: xml

I have this xml file:
[treas_yield.xml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56864497/xml/treas_yield.xml)

and I want to convert this file to a csv file:
2015-01-02T00:00:00, 0.02, 0.02 ...
 First time I need to parse the xml file.
I have this C++ code but I get an empty output. Please get me the correct solution.

```
pugi::xpath_query yield_query("/feed/entry");
pugi::xpath_query id_query("d:Id");
pugi::xpath_query date_query("d:NEW_DATE");
pugi::xpath_node_set xpath_yields = doc.select_nodes(yield_query);
int i=0;
for (pugi::xpath_node xpath_yield : xpath_yields)
{
    pugi::xml_node yield = xpath_yield.node();
    pugi::xml_node id = yield.select_node(id_query).node();
    pugi::xml_node date = yield.select_node(date_query).node();
    std::cout << i << " " << "d:Id: " << id.value() << "  "; //std::endl;
    std::cout << "d:NEW_DATE: " << date.value() << std::endl;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for parsing xml:

```
pugi::xpath_query yield_query("/feed/entry");
//pugi::xpath_query id_query("/m:properties/d:Id");
//pugi::xpath_query date_query("/m:properties/d:NEW_DATE");

pugi::xpath_node_set xpath_yields = doc.select_nodes(yield_query);
int i=0;
for (pugi::xpath_node xpath_yield : xpath_yields)
{
    pugi::xml_node yield = xpath_yield.node();
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << i << " Nod: " << yield.name() << " (" << yield.type() << "): " << yield.child_value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
    yield = yield.first_child();
    //std::cout << "Nod: " << yield.name() << " (" << yield.type() << "): " << yield.child_value() << std::endl;
    while (strcmp(yield.name(),"content")) {
        yield = yield.next_sibling();
        //std::cout << "Nod: " << yield.name() << " (" << yield.type() << "): " << yield.child_value() << std::endl;
    }
    yield = yield.first_child();//<m:properties>
    //std::cout << "Nod: " << yield.name() << " (" << yield.type() << "): " << yield.child_value() << std::endl;
    yield = yield.first_child();//<d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">
    std::cout << "Nod: " << yield.name() << " (" << yield.type() << "): " << yield.child_value() << std::endl;
    while (strcmp(yield.name(),"d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY")) {
        yield = yield.next_sibling();
        std::cout << "Nod: " << yield.name() << " (" << yield.type() << "): " << yield.child_value() << std::endl;
    }


    //pugi::xml_node id = yield.select_node(id_query).node();
    //pugi::xml_node date = yield.select_node(date_query).node();
    //std::cout << i << " " << "d:Id: " << id.value() << "  "; //std::endl;
    //std::cout << "d:NEW_DATE: " << date.value() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << i << std::endl;

    i++;
}
```